# given limited commands, return absolute difference between two registers

Tags: performance, assembly, cpu-registers, difference

Given the following commands:

- inc x - increment register x by 1
- dec x - decrease register x by 1
- jmp nez (label) - jump to label if previous command result is not zero
- halt - stop the program

write a program that compute the absolute difference between two registers a and b.

i found this question while looking for C questions for an upcoming interview in a company. so this is all that i have regarding the question, i'm assuming there's not third register we're allowed to use, and both registers contain a positive value.
this is my suggested solution, i would like to get some feedback on it, correction or better way to do it would be helpful.

```
decA:
    dec a;
    jmp nez decB;
    halt;
decB:
    dec b;
    jmp nez decA;
    halt;
```

at the end of the code, one of the registers would be 0 and the other would contain the absolute difference between the two registers. i'm sure there's a better solution, but can't find one under the assumptions.